# How can I insert more space in an equation for PDF and Mathjax rendering?

Tags: latex, markdown, mathjax

I'm working in a R Markdown file that I output as a PDF and as an HTML. The equations are typed with Latex syntax.

In the past, I used \vspace{xymm} which is perfectly fine for the PDF version but is not supported by Mathjax.

What are my options regarding achieving the same spacing in PDF and HTML?

```
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{bla bla }\\
\vspace{2mm}
\text{bla bla} & \text{bla bla}\\
\text{bla bla} & \text{bla bla}\\
\end{array}$$
```

If I knit this to a PDF the 2mm space will be included after the first "\text{bla bla} & \text{bla bla}\" line. If I knit it to a HTML the "\vspace{xymm}" will be written as a text and no space will be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{bla bla }\\[2mm]
\text{bla bla} & \text{bla bla}\\
\text{bla bla} & \text{bla bla}\\
\end{array}$$
```

which should do the same thing.

Comment: Please consider marking this as the correct answer, so that your question will ben shown as answered for others who are looking for the same thing in the future.  Also, an upvote is common as well (as there are some consequences for answers with zero votes, but I don[t recall what they are).

Comment: Hi Davide thanks for your explanation. I've marked it as correct and I've done my up vote (but it will not be shown as I have to less reputation).